Run a pretrained Image-2-Image model using diffusers without CUDA?
I need to run a pretrained SD model locally for a small proof of concept project generating images out of outer images. I want to use the python diffusers library for this but if there are better software for the job please let me know.
The problem is that im running a MacBook Air M1 so I cant use the example from the diffusers docs, which looks something like this
pipeline = AutoPipelineForImage2Image.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True)

pipeline.enable_model_cpu_offload()

init_image = load_image("https://huggingface.co/datasets/huggingface/documentation-images/resolve/main/diffusers/cat.png")

prompt = "cat wizard, gandalf, lord of the rings, detailed, fantasy, cute, adorable, Pixar, Disney, 8k"

image = pipeline(prompt, image=init_image).images[0]

Because it uses CUDA and as you know I don't have a NVidea card with CUDA.
So im wondering if this is possible to do using MPS or just using the CPU by itself, I know this works for text-2-image generation but I cant find any source that says its possible for image-2-image (or on how to do it)?
